# How add Excel.ChartObject that is not a chart sheet with AddOleObject?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, vsto

This is not a duplicate question because the other questions do not have solutions for regular chart objects but only cover chart sheets.

Question: I want to add an Excel chart (i.e. NOT a chart sheet) to PowerPoint by using AddOleObject. I do not want to use a clipboard solution for this.

I tried the following:

```
oSlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject(FileName:=$"{oChartObject.Parent.Parent.Path}\{oChartObject.Parent.Parent.Name}!{oChartObject.Parent.Name}!{oChartObject.Name}", Link:=Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse)
```

the FileName:= results in the following string:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\SomeWorkbook.xlsx!Sheet2!NameOfMyChartObject
```

But this fails (com exception E fail) and I do not understand how to fix it.

Comment: If I am not wrong, this method is to insert a file and not an object from inside that file. The `AddOLEObject` is the same as clicking `Insert Tab | Object | Create from file` in Powerpoint.

Comment: Apparently you can use this function to insert a chart sheet so I was thinking that it should also work for regular charts. Maybe somebody else know it for sure.